# How do I find coefficients of a product expansion

Tags: co.combinatorics, power-series, symmetric-functions, lambda-rings

Any power series $f(t) = 1 + t \mathbb{Z}[[t]]$ can be uniquely expanded in the following two ways:

$$1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i t^i = 
\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-t^i)^{-n_i}$$

Here, the $f_i$ and $n_i$ are integers.

> > Is there an explicit formula for the $n_i$ in terms of the $f_i$?

Similarly a power series $f(t, L) = 1 + t \mathbb{Z}[[t, L]]$ can be uniquely expanded

$$1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty f_{i,j} t^i L^j = 
\prod_{i=1}^\infty \prod_{j=0}^\infty (1-t^i L^j)^{-n_{i,j}}$$

> > How do I find the $n_{i,j}$ in terms of the $f_{i,j}$?

More generally, in an arbitrary $\lambda$-ring $\Lambda$, a power series $f(t) \in 1 + t \Lambda[[t]]$ can be uniquely expanded in the following two ways:

$$1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i t^i = 
\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-t^i)^{-n_i}$$

where the $f_i, n_i \in \Lambda$, and the exponent signifies 
$(1-t^i)^{-M} := \sum_{k=0}^\infty t^{ik} \mathrm{Sym}^k(M)$

> > Is there an explicit formula for the $n_i$ in terms of the $f_i$?

Comment: I am vaguely aware that there's an answer to this question of the form ``take a logarithm and do symmetric function combinatorics'', but I wasn't able to reconstruct the details.

Answer (score 5):

I'll use the notation $[t^i]$ to stand for the coefficient of $t^i$ in a Maclaurin series. Let

$$ C(i) = [t^i] \log(1+t F(t)) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j+1} [t^i] \dfrac{t^j F(t)^j}{j} 
 = \sum_{j=1}^i (-1)^{j+1} [t^{i-j}] \dfrac{F(t)^j}{j} $$
Then
$$
C(i) = [t^i] \log \prod_{j=1}^\infty (1-t^j)^{-n_j} =
 - \sum_{j | i} n_j [t^i] \log(1 - t^j) =  \sum_{j | i} \dfrac{j n_j}{i}$$
and then
$$ n_j = \sum_{i | j} \mu(j/i) \dfrac{i}{j} C(i)$$

Answer (score 3):

Robert Israel's answer works if you have access to the coefficients of $\log f(t)$, which isn't always the case (one example that comes to mind is when the $f_i$'s are classes of punctual Hilbert schemes, and you're trying to get invariants as in [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0473).)

To answer your question more specifically, here is my attempt at spelling out the strategy you mention. Let's start with the identity
$$\frac{1}{1-at}=\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(1-t^k)^{M_k(a)}},$$
where $M_k(a)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{d|k}a^d\mu(k/d)$ are the [necklace polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial).

Next, let $h_i\in \Lambda[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ be the [complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial). We have the following fundamental generating function
$$1+h_1t+h_2t^2+\cdots=\prod_{r\geq 1}\frac{1}{(1-x_rt)}.$$
So combining with our previous observation we have
$$1+h_1t+h_2t^2+\cdots=\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(1-t^k)^{M_k(x_1)+M_{k}(x_2)+\cdots}}.$$
Now, $n_k=\sum_r M_k(x_r)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{d|k}p_d(x_1,x_2,\dots) \mu(k/d)$, so to finish off we need to express the power sum symmetric functions, $p_k$, in terms of the $h_k$'s. This is given by [a variation of the Newton identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomials)
$$p_n(h_1,h_2,\dots)=(-1)^{n-1}\begin{vmatrix}h_1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & \\ 2h_2 & h_1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\ 3h_3 & h_2 & h_1 & 1 & \\ \vdots & & \\ nh_n & h_{n-1} & \cdots & & h_1\end{vmatrix}.$$

So the polynomials you're looking for are $$n_k(f_1,f_2,\dots)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{d|k}\mu(k/d)p_d(f_1,f_2,\dots).$$

Hope this helps.